# English wording around equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, equivalence-relations

What is the English word to mean an element of an equivalence class of an equivalence relation? In French we say "représentant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it a *representative* of the equivalence class.